# Example of Connected but Not-Path Connected Set

Tags: general-topology, connectedness, path-connected

$ L:= \{(1,0)\}\;\cup\; \bigcup_{n=1}^\infty L_n$ where $L_n:= \{(x,{x\over n})\in \Bbb R^2\mid \; x\in [0,1]\},\; n\in \Bbb N$.

---

I've been provided that the set L as an example of **Connected but not Path-connecte set**.

I would like to prove that the given L is connected but not-path-connected?

Below is my proof for connectedness, please check whether it's correct.

**Proof of Connected-ness>>**

If we choose two open sets $u,v$ in $\Bbb R^2 $ which are $ u = (1,0)$ and $ v = L \setminus \{(1,0)\} $ then A is connected.

**Proof of Path-Connected >>**

How to do this?

Comment: The proof for connectedness needs to work for *all* open sets $u,v$. Also, your $u$ is not open.

Comment: How could I make it general for all arbitral cases?

Answer (score 2):

### Proof of  connectedness

Let $U,V\subseteq \Bbb R^2$ be arbitrary open sets with $L\subseteq U\cup V$ and $L\cap U\cap V=\emptyset$. We want to show that $L\subseteq U$ or $L\subseteq V$.

One of them, wlog. $U$, contains the point $(1,0)$, hence also an open disk $B_r(1,0)$ of some positive radius $r$ around that point. For $N>\frac1r$, we have $(1,\frac1N)\in U$, hence $U$ intersects $L_N$. As $L_N$ is connected (it is homeomorphic with $[0,1]$), we conclude that $L_n\subseteq U$. In particular $(0,0)\in U$. But the $U$ intersects $L_n$ for all $n$, hence $L_n\subseteq U$ for all $n$, i.e., $\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty L_n\subseteq U$. As also $(1,0)\in U$, we have $L\subseteq U$.

### Disproof of path connectedness

Assume $L$ were path-connected. Then there exists a path from $(0,0)$ to $(1,0)$, i.e., a continuos map $\gamma\colon [0,1]\to L$ with $\gamma(0)=(0,0)$ and $\gamma(1)=(1,0)$.
Let $t_0=\sup\{\,t\in[0,1]\mid\gamma(t)=(0,0)\,\}$. By continuity of $\gamma$, also $\gamma(t_0)=(0,0)$.
Let $t_1=\inf\{\,t\in[t_0,1]\mid\gamma(t)=(1,0)\,\}$. Again by continuity of  $\gamma$, also $\gamma(t_0)=(1,0)$.
Then $p:=\gamma((t_0+t_1)/2)$ is $\ne(0,0)$ and $\ne (1,0)$, hence on one (and only one) $L_n$. But there is no path from $p$ to $(1,0)$ that does not pass through $(0,0)$ (to see this, note that $L\setminus\{(0,0)\}$ is not even connected).

Comment: I'v learned that for the proof of disconnected as follow:
$A \in M $ is disconnected if,
for two open sets $u, v$ in metric space with: 
(i) $(A\cap u)\cap(A\cap v) = \emptyset$

(ii) $A\cap u \neq \emptyset$

(iii) $A\cap v \neq \emptyset$

(iv) $(A\cap u)\cup(A\cap v) = A$

How can I logically construe your definition of connectedness from above definition?

Comment: What is the definition of homeomorphic? can't get this part : "As $L_N$ is connected (it is homeomorphic with $[0,1]$), we conclude that $L_n\subseteq U$."

Comment: @jackerysmith For the first point, you note that a space $A$ is disconnected if (and only if) we can find open $u,v$ such that (i),(ii),(iii) and (iv) hold.  Hagen's equivalent formulation is that a space $A$ is connected if and only if whenever we have $u$ and $v$ such that (i) and (iv) hold, then either (ii) or (iii) does not hold (otherwise, they all hold and $A$ is disconnected).  Now note that saying that $A\cap u=\emptyset$ or $A\cap v=\emptyset$, in the presence of (iv), is equivalent to saying that $A\cap v= A$ or $A\cap u=A$; i.e., $v\subseteq A$ or $u\subseteq A$.

Comment: For your second question, we say that a continuous map $\phi\colon X\to Y$ is a homeomorphism if it has a continuous inverse.  If there is a homeomorphism from $X$ to $Y$, then we say that $X$ and $Y$ are homeomorphic.  There's an obvious homemorphism from $[0,1]$ to $L_n$ given by $x\mapsto(x,x/n)$.  Now we use the fact that if $X$ is connected and $X$ is homeomorphic to $Y$ then $Y$ is connected.  You might like to prove this for yourself.

Comment: @John Gowers Got it. One more question - how could we know the fact that "the $U$ intersects $L_n$ for all $n$"?

Comment: @John Gowers and for the miscellaneous stuff, isn't that path (0,0) to (1,0) not (0,0) to (0,0). can't edit it since it's less than 6 characters by myself.

Comment: I can't understand why there is no path from $p$ to $(1,0)$ that does not pass through $(0,0)$ for the last part of disproof of not-path connected

Comment: @jackerysmith That follows from the previously proved fact that $(0,0)\in U$, since $(0,0)\in L_n$ for all $n$.

Comment: For your second comment, you are right and I have edited the answer.  For your third comment: suppose there were such a path $\gamma\colon[0,1]\to L\setminus\{(0,0)\}$.  Then the image of $\gamma$ would be a connected subset of $L\setminus\{(0,0)\}$ containing both $p$ and $(1,0)$.  But that is impossible: indeed, given $K\subset L\setminus\{(0,0)\}$ containing both $p\in L_n$ and $(1,0)$, we see that $V=K\cap (L_n\setminus\{(0,0)\})$ is both open and closed in $K$ and contains $p$ but not $(1,0)$.  Therefore, $V$ and $K\setminus V$ disconnect $K$.

Answer (score 1):

Your proof for connectedness does not make sense.  You need to prove that *for all* pairs $U,V$ of non-empty open subsets of $L$ such that $U\cup V=L$, you have $U\cap V\neq\emptyset$.  Instead, you've only mentioned *one choice* of $U$ and $V$ - and your set $u$ isn't open anyway.

Note that the set $L\setminus\{(0,1)\}$ is path connected (just take a path to the origin and then back out again) and hence connected.  Now notice that $(0,1)$ is contained in the closure of $L\setminus\{(0,1)\}$.  You can then apply the following result, which is not too difficult to prove:

**Theorem** Let $X$ be a connected subset of some space $M$ and suppose that $X\subset Y\subset \text{cl}X$.  Then $Y$ is connected.

To show that your space is not path connected, you will need to show that the point $(0,1)$ is not connected to the rest of the space by a path.  Specifically, let's show that there is no path from $(0,1)$ to $(1,1)$.  Indeed, suppose there were such a path $\gamma\colon[0,1]\to L$.

Let $B$ be the open ball of radius $1/2$ about $(0,0)$.  $L\setminus B$ is not connected (it is easy to find open sets $U,V$ that disconnect it), so any path from $(0,1)$ to $(1,1)$ must pass through $B$.  Let
$$
t=\inf\{s\in[0,1]\colon\gamma(s)\in B\}
$$

We claim that if $u< t$, then $\gamma(u)=(0,1)$.  Indeed, any path from $(0,1)$ to any point in $L\setminus\{(0,1)\}$ must pass through $B$, so if $\gamma(u)\in L\setminus\{(0,1)\}$ then there must be some $v\le u<t$ such that $\gamma(v)\in B$, contradicting the definition of $t$.  Since $\{(0,1)\}$ is closed, it follows that $\gamma(t)=(0,1)$.

But we also have
$$
t\in\text{cl}\gamma^{-1}(B)\subset\gamma^{-1}(\text{cl}B)
$$

and so $\gamma(t)\in\text{cl}(B)$.  But this is a contradiction, since $(0,1)$ is not in the closure of $B$.

I think the proof can be tidied up a bit, but that's the idea.