# Any 2 points of a open bounded connected set can be connected by a curve that can be covered by at most $k$ balls of a fixed radius: how to prove it?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, functional-analysis, geometry, analysis

I am trying to understand a property stated during my math class today, which was presented as something trivial (but for me this is not the case). The property is the following.

Let $\Omega$ be an open bounded subset in $\mathbb{R}^N$, $N\ge 2$. Let $\Omega_1\subset\Omega$ be an arbitrary open, bounded and connected subset. Choose $r>0$ such that $r<\frac12 \text{dist}(\Omega_1, \partial\Omega)$. There exists $k\in\mathbb{N}$ such that any two points $x_1, x_2\in\Omega_1$ can be connected in $\Omega_1$ by a curve that can be covered by at most $k$ balls of radius $r$ with centers in  $\Omega_1$.

This statement seems to me far from obvious. Could someone please help me with its proof or give me a reference?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Do you mean $k$ instead of $m$ when you wrote "at most $m$ balls..." ?

Comment: Note that the assumption that $\Omega_1$ is *open* is needed.  It isn't generally the case that a connected subset of $\mathbb R^2$ is [path-connected](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2271218/example-of-connected-but-not-path-connected-set).

Comment: @coffeemath you are right, I edited the question.

Comment: @hardmath do you mean that, if $\Omega_1$ is also open, then it is path connected and then "There exists $k\in\mathbb{N}$ such that any two points $x_1, x_2\in\Omega_1$ can be connected in $\Omega_1$ by a curve that can be covered by at most $k$ balls of radius $r$ with centers in $\Omega_1$? Actually I don't understand the "at most $k$ balls of radius $r$ with centers in $\Omega_1$."

Comment: Your conclusion "that any two points $x_1,x_2\in Ω_1$ can be connected in $Ω_1$ by a curve" sounds like a claim that $\Omega_1$ is *path-connected*.  The construction required is more elaborate than that, as one needs to cover the curve (path?) with balls of "radius $r$ with centers in $\Omega_1$".  I'm pointing out that the "statement is far from obvious" as indeed it is false.  It looks to me like assuming $\Omega_1$ is open (as the notation suggests) will fix that difficulty.

Comment: @hardmath I see. So let us assume $\Omega_1$ is open (for simplicity, I edit the question in that way). It remains to prove that "there exists $k\in\mathbb{N}$ such that..." Could you please help me with proving that part? Or at least give a reference?

Comment: I have an idea that the exercise was intended to use compactness.  Since any particular curve (path) is a compact subset of $\Omega_1$, and since it is covered by all open balls of radius $r$ with centers in $\Omega_1$, it would be covered by a finite number of such balls.  What is required to make the number of balls *uniform* with respect to all endpoints $x_1,x_2 \in \Omega_1$.  I suspect this also follows from a compactness argument, but more thinking is needed to write up something.

Comment: @hardmath thank you for your comment. If you get to a result, could you please write down an answer? I am really in trouble with that especially because it was presented as a trivial result. Thank you again.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Cover $\bar \Omega_1$ by balls of radius $r$ with centers in $\Omega_1$. Since $\bar \Omega_1$ is compact, we can choose finitely many ($k$) such balls. these $k$ balls cover $\Omega_1$, hence any path in $\Omega_1$.